# Track conversion-rate in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets

Via Google spreadsheet wie track a lot of data (i.e. ga:bounceRate) from Analytics and Search Console. But I cant find, what to metric to set, to get the conversion-rate by page? I thought something like ga:conversionRate?

I cant find the right here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the metric `ga:productAddsToCart`